# Why can't my facebook fql query more than 2 facebook values?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

Trying to create a facebook app just to learn and coming across a strange phenomenon that I'm not sure what to make of.

I understand all the JSON conversions but it seems I can't query more than 2 facebook values at a time when supposedly I'm supposed to be able to...(??? sorry if that was confusion). Below is my code taken out of context.

```
$query="query".$i;
$idarray["$query"]="SELECT+pic,name+FROM+user+WHERE+uid=".$friend_id[$i];
```

When I try to query more than pic and name, it only gives me two. It will not let me query something like "pic,name,username" etc. Does anyone know the reason why? And if so, how can I solve this to query more than 2?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This works for me fine, there's not enough information here to know what your problem actually is - when you call the API manually does it return the correct data?

Comment: Hi Igy! So when you query "SELECT+pic,name,username,something else, something else+FROM+user+WHERE+uid= . $friend_id[$]" Do you actually get all that you query? For me, I can only get two subjects at a time. If I do another query round for another two subjects, it will return me those two subjects. However, the overall conclusion is I can't make 4 subject queries with one SELECT query. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me, i can't determine what you're doing that's causing this to not work:

```
select uid, name, first_name, middle_name, last_name, sex, locale, pic_small_with_logo, pic_big_with_logo, pic_square_with_logo, pic_with_logo, username from user where uid in (4,5,6,7)
```

Return is:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": 4, 
      "name": "Mark Zuckerberg", 
      "first_name": "Mark", 
      "middle_name": "", 
      "last_name": "Zuckerberg", 
      "sex": "male", 
      "locale": "en_US", 
      "pic_small_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDIpcVgo2Fz4U4e&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F157340_4_3955636_t.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "pic_big_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCa1XUcpDZryPMM&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F49942_4_1525300_n.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "pic_square_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBYWqMD88h5CkD3&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F157340_4_3955636_q.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "pic_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDqZdUCq_U_senP&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F157340_4_3955636_s.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "username": "zuck"
    }, 
    {
      "uid": 5, 
      "name": "Chris Hughes", 
      "first_name": "Chris", 
      "middle_name": "", 
      "last_name": "Hughes", 
      "sex": "male", 
      "locale": "en_US", 
      "pic_small_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBm5Un8ZmN8OMxy&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F211833_5_64370680_t.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "pic_big_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQB0gVdhHSj4v6gN&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F211833_5_64370680_n.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "pic_square_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBTEKDI6lBvbtcE&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F211833_5_64370680_q.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "pic_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCYybISnGDBbBfO&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F211833_5_64370680_s.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "username": "ChrisHughes"
    }, 
    {
      "uid": 6, 
      "name": "Dustin Moskovitz", 
      "first_name": "Dustin", 
      "middle_name": "", 
      "last_name": "Moskovitz", 
      "sex": "male", 
      "locale": "en_US", 
      "pic_small_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAq87DIy_gbhxVb&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F173132_6_1123895199_t.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "pic_big_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBtlc6qP74cEMpQ&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F173132_6_1123895199_n.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "pic_square_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAumnkA5BT4KUVk&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F173132_6_1123895199_q.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "pic_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBJZfp6ui5GWXRZ&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F173132_6_1123895199_s.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "username": "moskov"
    }, 
    {
      "uid": 7, 
      "name": "Arie Hasit", 
      "first_name": "Arie", 
      "middle_name": "", 
      "last_name": "Hasit", 
      "sex": "male", 
      "locale": "en_US", 
      "pic_small_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAVKTiIJr8Yf9KR&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F23251_7_6318_t.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "pic_big_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDonksAfqN0W_GS&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F23161_7_4183_n.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "pic_square_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAP10kv_ZDVA6XF&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F23251_7_6318_q.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "pic_with_logo": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCL96KpL_7TLRar&url=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Ffbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\u00252Fhprofile-ak-snc4\u00252F23251_7_6318_s.jpg&logo&v=5", 
      "username": "arie.hasit"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Igy, how is it that your query doesn't require a + between the letters. Here's another example of code which won't query more than 2 elements: $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . '/fql?q=SELECT+first_name,pic+FROM+user+WHERE+uid=me()'
    . '&' . $access_token;
    
    $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
  $fql_query_me = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);

Comment: The query needs to be encoded before you pass it to the API, but browsers do that automatically - that query also works fine for me and includes all requested fields

Comment: Hmm... Hi Igy, random question-- what would you recommend as a unique id to all users? Something that would always accurately id every fb user everytime.

Comment: I've found that the user id for my friends, and then user ids for my friend's friends overlap. So one of my friends may have a user id "4567" and when sourcing from my friend's friends, his friend (different person) will also have "4567"

Comment: That is absolutely not the case; there must be something wrong with your code stripping some of the digits or parsing 64 bit integers as 32 bit, if that happened you'd see 4294967296 appearing multiple times